# Laravel Mail Working locally but not on server

Tags: laravel

I have created a simple contact form to send mail  on website owner email id ,  everything is working fine on my local server I'm getting the mail, but when uploaded on hosting its giving me below error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io
>   [Connection refused #111]

When I googled this error I came to know instead of SMTP mail driver use sendmail or mailgun, yeah when I did this I didn't get error and got the success msg, but not receiving the mail.

Can you tell me where am I going wrong?. I have already tried `config:clear` cmd .

**.env:**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=myusername
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

**mailcontroller:**

```
Mail::send(new SendMail);
return back()->with('msg','Thank You For Contacting us,we will get back to you soon');
```

**sendmail.php:**

```
public function build(Request $request)
{
    return $this->view('email',['fname'=>$request->fname,'lname'=>$request->lname,'msg'=>$request->msg,'mobile'=>$request->mobile,'email'=>$request->email])->to('kunal.rajput2511@gmail.com')->subject('Website Contact Form');
}
```

Comment: Please check port used to send email is allowed on the server first. You can try `MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` as well

Comment: yeah i tried , not working

Comment: I'm using godaddy hosting , can you guide me to disable the firewall

Comment: Please try php's `mail()` function first to check whether `mail` is sent or not then contact the hosting provider to verify if any rules applied for `mail`.

Comment: Yeah Thanks it was my hosting issue, its resolved from hosting provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try php's `mail()` function first to check whether mail is sent or not then contact the `hosting provider` to verify if any rules applied for `mail`.